# Internet Explorer plugin to run fast it like Google Chrome for angular spring boot websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring-boot

We are working on website having lots of data on home page built using Spring boot + angular js in jhipster. The home page and other pages have drop downs those were loaded with thousands of data. Also table have big number of rows loaded with large number of data.

Site work fine on Google Chrome, Firefox, but as I load site on IE 11 version, IE get hang and throw error of not responding. As IE is slower to load java script due to its java script engine loading time slower than other browsers.

Specially when I updated combo box with angular chosen (as we need searchable combo) then loading of pages drop down.

```
<select data-placeholder="Please choose" class="form-control localytics-chosen" id="myId" name="myName" ng-model="vm.myList" ng-change="vm.setMethod(vm.myList,'ns')" style="width: 373px;height: 34px;padding: 6px 12px;" chosen="" options="reg as reg.rFullName for reg in vm.cRegs">
 </select>
```

I want to optimized the website. What can be better solution for it. 
I have tried one-time binding for loading values in drop down, but it didn't made big changes in loading speed.

Can anyone suggest better options to speed up performance ?

What is best plugin for IE so that performance can be speed up, I have tried Chrome Frame but this didn't changes anything. What is the best plugin to run website to speed up loading.

Comment: IE sucks, specially before Edge (and Edge is not that much better), there is really no much you can do about it. But I did notice the statement `have drop downs those were loaded with thousands of data` - drop down is really not meant for thousands of data.

Comment: Agreed!! We need to provide searchable angular chosen dropdown to select an item from thousands of data. Can you suggest any plugin for IE?

Comment: @NeelamSharma if you have thousands of options in your dropdown, some sort of autocomplete widget is probably a more suitable option for a better user experience, and it will avoid the performance issues you are having. It will replace your `<select>` element and will be just a javascript widget and isn't IE-specific. There may be one which fits in specifically with angular, but otherwise the JQueryUI autocomplete is a good example of this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ It can take data from a pre-loaded array, or an ajax source, or any custom function you like.